# How to calculate average session duration by login instance in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**users**

```
id    email
-------------------------------------------------------------
1     apple@apple.com
2     google@google.com
```

**user_session_logs**

```
id    user_id    start_timestamp          end_timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------
1     1          2016-01-01 12:00:00      2016-01-01 13:00:00
2     2          2016-01-01 14:00:00      2016-01-01 15:00:00
3     2          2016-02-03 06:00:00      2016-02-03 06:30:00
4     1          2016-03-03 05:00:00      2016-03-03 06:00:00
5     1          2016-04-03 07:00:00      2016-04-03 08:30:00
```

I want to calculate session duration distributions stratified by login instance (first login, second login, etc).
So given the data above, I want to get

**results**

```
login_instance    average_session_duration_minutes
-------------------------------------------------------------
1                   60 (this is the average of all user's 1st session duration)
2                   45 (this is the average of all user's 2nd session duration)
3                   90 (this is the average of all user's 3rd session duration)
```

Any ideas how this can be done in a mysql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a subselect to count the login instances by counting the number of previous entries (i.e. with a lesser user_session_log id) for the same user_id:

```
SELECT login_instance, AVG(session_duration_minutes) AS average_session_duration_minutes
FROM
(SELECT *,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM user_session_logs usl2
         WHERE usl2.user_id = usl.user_id AND usl2.id <= usl.id) AS login_instance,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_timestamp, end_timestamp) AS session_duration_minutes
 FROM user_session_logs usl) subq
GROUP BY login_instance;
```

See demo here: http://rextester.com/VVT36119

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

```
select 
    us.id,  
    usl.id, 
    usl.user_id, 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,usl.start_timestamp ,usl.start_timestamp)
from user as us ,user_sessions_log as usl
where us.id=usl.id
Group By us.id;
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want value per individual user, I am looking for average per login instance, as given in my example data.

Comment: Than you don't have to do join query ? login_instance value will come from which field?